# Order Categories by Hierarchy?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I want order my categories by hierarchy. But I want to use custom select name, id and class like this:

```
<select name="kategorisec" id="cat" class="postform">
...
</select>
```

and I want to use my custom value like this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></option>
```

But it doesn't ordering by hierarchy. How can I order the categories by hierarchy (with levels)? Thanks in advance. My all codes:

```
<?php $args2 = array(  
'taxonomy'     => 'fgaleri',    
'orderby'      => 'name', 
'show_count'   => 1,
'hierarchical' => 1,    
'title_li'     => ''  
);
?>
<?php $cats = get_categories($args2); ?>
<select name="kategorisec" id="cat" class="postform">
<option value="">Kategori Seç ve Ara</option>
<?php foreach ($cats as $cat) : ?>    
<option value="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>">
<?php echo $cat->name; ?></option>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did! I found a function to make option value='slug'.

The function:

```
class SH_Walker_TaxonomyDropdown extends Walker_CategoryDropdown{
function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
    $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);
    $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats', $category->name, $category);
    if( !isset($args['value']) ){

        $args['value'] = ( $category->taxonomy != 'category' ? 'slug' : 'id' );
    }
    $value = ($args['value']=='slug' ? $category->slug : $category->term_id );
    $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".$value."\"";
    if ( $value === (string) $args['selected'] ){ 
        $output .= ' selected="selected"';
    }
    $output .= '>';
    $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
    if ( $args['show_count'] )
        $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;('. $category->count .')';
    $output .= "</option>\n";
    }
}
```

And my all codes:

```
<?php /** * Displays the Pagination in Custom loop * */?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php global $wp_query;
$aranan= $_GET['s']; 
$kategorim = intval($_GET['cat']);
$kateg1= $_GET['kategorisec'];
if (intval($kateg1)<0) { $kateg = ""; } else { $kateg = $kateg1; }
$myterm = get_term( $kategorim, 'fgaleri' ); 
global $myslug;
$myslug = $myterm->slug; ?>
<div id="content">
<?php $rakam= 0;
//The query
$wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' =>'fotograf', 's' => $aranan, 'paged' => $paged, 'taxonomy' => 'fgaleri', 'fgaleri' => $kateg ) );
//The loop
?><div id="FGaleri_2"><div id="FGaleri_Ic"><div id="FGaleriBaslik">Fotoğraf Galerisi     <form action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>" id="searchformfoto" method="get" name="searchform">
<?php $args = array( 'walker'=> new SH_Walker_TaxonomyDropdown(), 'class' => 'postform', 'id' => 'kategorisec', 'name' => 'kategorisec', 'value'=>'slug', 'taxonomy' => 'fgaleri', 'show_option_none' => 'Kategori Seç ve Ara', 'hierarchical' => 1 ); wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
<div id="aramabolumufoto">
<input name="s" id="sfoto" type="text" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="fotograf" />
<input id="searchsubmitfoto" type="submit" value="Ara"/>
</div></form></div>
<div class="FGaleri_Ic_2">
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post(); $rakam++; ?>
<div class="FGaleriItem2" style="<?php if ($rakam % 5 == 0 ) { ?>margin-right: 2px;<?php } ?>">
<?php 
$termargs=array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'desc');
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID , 'fgaleri', $termargs );
$t = count($terms);
if ($t>0) { ?>
<div class="fkategori">
<?php $c = 0;
foreach($terms as $term) {  
$c++;  
if ($c==$t)   
{   echo '<a class="foto_kategori" href="'. home_url() . '/?kategorisec=' . $term->slug . '&post_type=fotograf" title="' . $term->name . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a> ';  }} ?>
</div><?php } ?>
<div class="ResimUst">
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );$url2 = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/timthumb.php?src=" . $url . "&amp;w=100&amp;h=100&amp;zc=1"; ?>
<img src="<?php if(get_option('of_timthumb')=="true") { echo $url2; } else { echo $url; } ?>" alt="" title="" width="100" height="100" /></a>
<?php } ?>
</div><div class="ResimAlt"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a></div></div>
<?php if (($rakam % 5 == 0 ) && ($rakam > 4)) { ?><div class="clearboth"></div><?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?></div></div></div><div class="clearboth"></div>
<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) {     
wp_pagenavi(); 
//function call for plugin pagination( wp pagenavi plugin)
} else { ?>     
<div id="navigasyon"><span class="previous-entries">
<?php next_posts_link('« Daha Eski Fotoğraflar'); ?></span>
<span class="next-entries"><?php previous_posts_link('Daha Yeni Fotoğraflar »'); ?></span>
</div><?php } //endif ?><?php ?></div><?php get_sidebar(); ?></div><?php get_footer(); ?>
```